# list memory usage in ipython and jupyter

Tags: python, numpy, memory, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have a few (almost ten) Gb of memory taken by the ipython kernel. I think this is coming from large objects (matrices, lists, numpy arrays, ...) that I might have produced during some operation and now I do not need anymore.

I would like to **list all of the objects I have defined** and **sort them** by their memory footprint. Is there a simple way to do that? For certain types there is `nbytes` method, but not for all ... so I am looking for a general way to list all objects I have made and their memory occupation.

Comment: `import sys; sorted([(x, sys.getsizeof(x)) for x in dir()], key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check the memory usage of objects in iPython?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563840/how-can-i-check-the-memory-usage-of-objects-in-ipython)

Comment: Not a duplicate, he's asking how to find objects he doesn't know the name of.  @Abdou you should make that an answer I think.

Comment: Thanks! the issue with `getsizeof` is what units does it use? the documentation says bytes, but it cannot possibly be right as for me it shows `[('T2T_cij_lsi200_600histo', 72),
 ('T2T_cij_lsi20_600histo', 71),
 ('T2T_cij_lsi50_600histo', 71),
 ('cluster_single_author', 70),
 ('SpectralBiclustering', 69),
 ('SpectralCoclustering', 69),
 ('begin_of_allocation', 68),
 ('feature2feature_log', 68,....` and the frist objects are about 1 Gb (I know from numpy .nbytes and from pickling them). Furthermore doing `%whos` these symbols are listed with the correct size around 1 Gb

Comment: Actually should be: `import sys; sorted([(x, sys.getsizeof(globals().get(x))) for x in dir()], key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)`. The previous one was getting the sizes of the strings. This one actually gets the objects.

Comment: `getsizeof` for a list is just the size of the pointers in the list, not the size of the objects pointed to.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052836/getsizeof-returns-the-same-value-for-seemingly-different-lists

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Assuming that you are using `ipython` or `jupyter`, you will need to do a little bit of work to get a list all of the objects ***you*** have defined. That means taking everything available in `globals()` and filtering out objects that are `modules`, `builtins`, `ipython objects`, etc. Once you are sure you have those objects, then you can proceed to grabbing their sizes with `sys.getsizeof`. This can be summed up as follows:

```
import sys

# These are the usual ipython objects, including this one you are creating
ipython_vars = ['In', 'Out', 'exit', 'quit', 'get_ipython', 'ipython_vars']

# Get a sorted list of the objects and their sizes
sorted([(x, sys.getsizeof(globals().get(x))) for x in dir() if not x.startswith('_') and x not in sys.modules and x not in ipython_vars], key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Please keep in mind that for python objects (those created with python's builtin functions), `sys.getsizeof` will be very accurate. But it can be a bit inaccurate on objects created using third-party libraries. Furthermore, please be mindful that `sys.getsizeof` adds an additional garbage collector overhead if the object is managed by the garbage collector. So, some things may look a bit heavier than they actually are.

As a side note, `numpy`'s `.nbytes` method can be somewhat misleading in that it does not include memory consumed by non-element attributes of the array object.

Comment: super working code.. tried lot of other places but the size values were incorrect. thanks a  ton!!

Comment: Didn't seem to work for me — I dont use ipython so modified like so `sorted([(x, sys.getsizeof(globals().get(x))) for x in dir() if not x.startswith('_') and x not in sys.modules], key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)` (no `ipython_vars`) but the value of `hi` is `1` and it registered as `28`...? Is this the garbage collector you were talking about, because `i` has a value of `43892978` and it registers as 28 too.

Comment: fantastic, I had no idea how to list these or what the default objects were, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I like the answer @Abdou provided! I would only add the following suggestion. Instead of a list of tuples, I would convert it to a dictionary.

```py
import sys

# These are the usual ipython objects, including this one you are creating
ipython_vars = ["In", "Out", "exit", "quit", "get_ipython", "ipython_vars"]

# Get a sorted list of the objects and their sizes
mem = {
    key: value
    for key, value in sorted(
        [
            (x, sys.getsizeof(globals().get(x)))
            for x in dir()
            if not x.startswith("_") and x not in sys.modules and x not in ipython_vars
        ],
        key=lambda x: x[1],
        reverse=True,
    )
}
```

Then if I wanted to get the total amount in MBs, all I'd have to do is:

```py
sum(mem.values()) / 1e6
```

Comment: Great stuff @daniel-cárdenas. Perhaps, you meant this 

`sum(mem.values())/1e6`

Comment: Correct! Nice catch @djoguns