# Python - function for memory list usage gives empty list

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to pass this code (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40997868/9537439) answer):

```
import sys

# These are the usual ipython objects, including this one you are creating
ipython_vars = ['In', 'Out', 'exit', 'quit', 'get_ipython', 'ipython_vars']

# Get a sorted list of the objects and their sizes
sorted([(x, sys.getsizeof(globals().get(x))/1e6) for x in dir() if not x.startswith('_') and x not in sys.modules and x not in ipython_vars], key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

To a function:

```
def memory_obj_list():
    import sys

    # These are the usual ipython objects, including this one you are creating
    ipython_vars = ['In', 'Out', 'exit', 'quit', 'get_ipython', 'ipython_vars']

    # Get a sorted list of the objects and their sizes
    a = sorted([(x, sys.getsizeof(globals().get(x))/1e6) for x in dir() if not x.startswith('_') and x not in sys.modules and x not in ipython_vars], key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return(a)
```

But when I use the function just like:

```
memory_obj_list()
```

It returns an empty list. If I run the code, it works perfectly. Why?

Comment: Are you importing the function from a module/file or are you defining it in your shell? The "global" namespace for a function will be bound to the module where it was defined

Comment: I'm defining it in the first cells of the notebook and running it well after

Comment: @IainShelvington in that case, do you know how could I make that the "global" namespace can read outside the function?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what notebook/tool you are using but `dir()` returns names in the local scope which may be the issue, try printing `globals()` in your function to see if you do get the names you expect because I think printing `dir()` will not output much